# COD4: Modern Warfare Single Player close unexpectedly

Tags: call-of-duty-4-modern-warfare

I have a problem with my COD4's iw3sp.exe, as i run the game, it exited during intro/load of the game without any message. How can i fix this? Running on Windows 7 32-bit.

*Multiplayer works just fine

Comment: Plugging in the mic worked for me when I had the problem in the past.

Comment: We'd need some more information, like: What have you tried? Is it the Steam version? Any mods? Is it up-to-date?